# Interrupted system call for posix_memalign

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

I am getting this exception with posix_memalign. Any idea as to why we get it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am getting the output to my log.

Comment: @Mat: I have overloaded the posix_memalign. That was working fine. But now, i have pou a flag to it. `if(flag){ return ob.registerPosix(memptr, alignment,size,LT_posix_memalign)} else return LT_POSIX_MEMALIGN(memptr, alignment, size)` This whole code is inside the `int posix_memalign( )` function.

Comment: registerPosix - simply records leaks. Thus, is flag is set, we check leaks, else not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved: The thing is the alignment boundary should be a multiple of 2 and `sizeof(void *)`. So if posinter size is 4 bytes, the second argument should be 4, 8, 16 etc. Instead of that i was putting it as only multiple of 2, and hence it was crashing.

```
Wrong usage: crashes
posix_memalign(&addr, 2, 8);

Correct usage:
 posix_memalign(&addr, 4, 8); // Second argument multiple of void* and 2
```

Comment: Looks like your mistake was not checking the return value of `posix_memalign` for failure.

Comment: Yes, i was not checking for errno. I was more concerned with leaks :(

Comment: Checking for `errno` is not correct with `posix_memalign`. The error number is simply the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Interrupted system calls are usually the result of a system call being interrupted.  In other words, the process is receiving a signal while the call is executing.